# Loading modal's html with ajax and script

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

So, I am developing an application that requires me to build a wizard html structure and give special behavior **in a modal**. My applications is made in Laravel and the problem is the following:

I need that every time that the modal opens load the HTML structure by an ajax call, then append the html body to the .modal-content div. I have no problem doing this, the problem comes when I try to execute the JavaScript code, it just doest seem to respond.

The structure is the following:

incomes/index.blade.php

```
    @section("modals")
        <div class="modal fade" id="incomesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="incomesModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
@section("modalsScript")

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $('#incomesModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/incomes/newModal",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#incomesModal .modal-content').html(data);
                    }

                });

            });

            $(".income-type").on("click", function(){

                alert("clicked");

            });

        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

incomes/modal.blade.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="incomesModalLabel">Este ingreso se relaciona mejor con...</h4>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div id="incomeSelectType">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="income-type " id="income-type-first" data-type="unit">
                    <h5>Ingreso por Venta de Unidades</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="income-type " id="income-type-second" data-type="hour">
                    <h5>Ingreso por Facturación de Horas</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="income-type " id="income-type-third" data-type="recurring">
                    <h5>Ingreso Recurrente/Subscripciones</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="income-type " id="income-type-fourth" data-type="other">
                    <h5>Otro tipo de Ingreso</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="income-type-first-box" style="display: none;">
        VU
    </div>
    <div id="income-type-second-box" style="display: none;">
        FH
    </div>
    <div id="income-type-third-box" style="display: none;">

        @include("incomes.recurringCharges.create")

    </div>
    <div id="income-type-fourth-box" style="display: none;">
        OI
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" id="controles">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p align="left" class="mar-l20 delete"  data-dismiss="modal" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="display:block;"></span> Eliminar
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p align="right"  class="mar-r20 mar-t20">
                            <span style="display:none;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" style="color:orange;"></span> <a id="incomes-back">Regresar</a> |
                            </span>
            <a id="incomes-next">Siguiente</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" style="color:orange;"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p align="left">
                Avance para completar este dato:
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p align="right">
                100%
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="progress" id="incomeProgress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 00%">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I have shorten the code so it is easy to understand.
Also note, that this code works when embebed directly without an ajax call.

So, after when the modal is shown the ajax code brings the HTML and inserts in  $('#incomesModal .modal-content'), the SCRIPT has been loaded even before the HTML structure has been loaded, but, when I try to click to any $(".income-type") box nothing happens!

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: you should return a json not the modal body , the modal structure needs to be on the page, you just apend the content

Comment: @madalinivascu I need to return the HTML structure. This structure has several JS behaviors that change the HTML structure of the modal body. I am not looking to return data, but the brand new HTML structure after being opened.

Comment: you can reset them at `show.bs.modal`

Comment: Just edited my answer. I've seen many examples about "reseting data" at show.bs.modal and nothing reloads the HTML strututure as it was originally.

Comment: you mean question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about event delegation:
Try:

```
 $("body").on("click",'.income-type',function(){

                alert("clicked");

});
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I will look for info about event delegation, which in fact, I don't know.